# Puppeteer VUE JS problems with HTTPS

Tags: node.js, vue.js, testing, puppeteer

I have a problem with executing tests served from NODE

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at https://localhost:8087
at navigate (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/FrameManager.ts:190:13)

Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total
Tests:       7 failed, 7 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.093s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dsf-frontend@0.1.0 test:e2e: `vue-cli-service test:unit -c jest.e2e.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the dsf-frontend@0.1.0 test:e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/xxxxxx/.npm/_logs/2021-04-13T10_41_31_417Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Could you give the following details, please? (1) What is the platform where you run the tests (in Docker/CI, locally on Linux/Windows/Mac)? (2) Your version of Node; (3) Version of Puppeteer; (4) your `puppeteer.launch` and (5) `page.goto` scripts in the tests. (6) Are you sure your localhost has SSL? Without these it is hard to tell what could be the problem.

Comment: VUE_APP_BUILD_TARGET=club vue-cli-service serve, talking with API severed by local Docker on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, Node v10.24.1, Puppeter 8, beforeAll(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    defaultViewport: { width: 0, height: 0 }, // force viewport to window size
    dumpio: true,
    timeout: 0,
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox', // it's fine, this is a container
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--window-size=1920,1080',
      '--start-maximized'
    ]
  });
https://localhost:8085

Answer (score 0):

This error was solved by updating certificates and after change the node version to v10.24.1.
However, I have a problem with timeouts when the test is longer than 5000 ms.

: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

```
  30 | const testAndScreenshot = function (url: string): ((name: string, func: (page: puppeteer.Page) => void) => Promise<void>) {
  31 |   return async function (name, func) {
> 32 |     test(name, async () => {
     |     ^
  33 |       // for subsequent tests, we leave the page logged in, unless we need to switch to testing a different app
  34 |       if (!page || page.isClosed() || !page.url().includes(url)) {
  35 |         page = await browser.newPage();
```